# You went to the casino again

Tags: mathematics, probability, algebra

> You went to the casino again and saw a cardboard, with the following written on it:
>
> > There are $\color{brown}{\text{dirt}}$ coins. Every time, you pay \$$10$. Then the coins will be thrown, and you get \$$n$    where $n$ is the number of coins that lands head.
>
> Then a guy told you,"It is expected to lose \$$1$ every time you play once on that stall, don't play it."
>
> How many coins are there at the stall?

---

Problem by me.

---

My previous problem about the casino has received good attention. This time, I originally wanted the answerers to use the identities about binomial coefficients. Please reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expected loss of \$$1$ translates to

> a payout of \$$9$ for your \$$10$ stake.

Assuming that the coins are fair, and have 50% chance of landing heads,

> **18 coins** would be expected to give an average of 9 heads, because 9 is 50% of 18.

However,

> The full problem without that assumption is unsolvable, as there could be any number of double-tail coins added without affecting the expected number of heads, and/or up to 9 double-head coins (each replacing a pair of fair coins)